# Best library to store and manage 36,000 contracts

Tags: document-library, records-management

I  have a client who has over 36,000 documents that he would like to move to a SharePoint library.  We have moved the 5,000 list view limit, but I am wondering if perhaps another library would fit their needs better.  This is in SP2010 but we are moving to 2013 soon.

Comment: Paul's answer below is absolutely right - the 5K limit is only for how many documents can be shown in a single view before issues start creeping up. I've had document libraries with well over a million docs in them before, no problems. Also note that increasing the listview threshold will not change the fact that 5000+ documents in a single view will likely cause slowness & glitches, maybe even browser crashes.

Comment: I worked a project that involved migrating multi millions of documents into Sharepoint with metadata. We used Blob Storage and kept the business units in separate Web Applications, but it worked out.

Answer (score 9):

What does "moved the 5,000 list view limit" mean?

The Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013 shows that the limit for items in a list/library is 30M. (As far back as SP2007 it was 5M). So there is no concern for 36K items.

However, retrieving more that 5K items in a single operation (a view) will cause performance degradation. That is why the list view throttle was implemented. I recommend leaving that throttle unchanged.

Do you have a business case for reading more than 5K items in a single operation? The out of the box list views show items in pages of 100, and that meets most end user requirements.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's referring to the listview threshold under resource throttling - could be wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at configuring BLOB into a document center in SharePoint 2010. Moving to SharePoint 2013 will be a little challenging.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to List View threshold,  this suggests that each view on your list should have less then 5000 items,  your list can still hold around 30 Million rows. Make sure to have some indexed columns and create views with more number of filters,  36000 is still a very small number as far as SharePoint capabilities are concerned.

Move over you can disable threshold settings for specific list using powershell [Disable threshold on a list](http://thesharepointfarm.com/2012/12/disable-throttling-on-a-list-by-list-basis/)

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: We disabled the threshold limit, thanks for you help

Comment: Glad that it worked,  mark it as answer if it helped